# Getting documents from MongoDB as PHP objects

Tags: php, mongodb

I am developing a PHP application using the Twitter API.
I have already achieved the data store from REST API(format JSON) in a MongoDB which can later be accessed by my web application.
I want to return a document from mongodb is a PHP object, not an array.Because, the PHP Driver return always MongoDB documents as arrays.
I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an example MongoDB collection of documents:

```
{
    _id : "my_unique_id_1",
    myfield1 : 100,
    myfield2 : "myvalue"
}
```

you should be able to perform action like following:

```
$myobject = (object)$mycollection->findOne(array("_id" => "my_unique_id_1"));
echo($myobject->myfield1);
```

In general, there is always a possibility to convert PHP array to php object like below:

```
$php_array = array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2");
$php_object = (object)$php_array;
echo($php_object->key1);  // should give "value1"
```

Here you can also find some information on casting between object and array types in PHP:

**[PHP - Types - Object casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)**

**[PHP - Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)**

Comment: Hi. I'll gladly try. I've added an answer on your second question. Please try.

Comment: i have already answered u on the second question,could you please check it?